# Is there a D-SLR that can record video with continuous autofocus?

Tags: autofocus, video, continuous-autofocus

Is there a D-SLR (including the new Nikon and Canon 60D) that can take video with continuous autofocus? On cameras that don't support that feature, is it possible to autofocus by pressing a button while shooting a video?

I'm looking into a getting a new DSLR and the video feature is quite important to  me. Wondering if the existing cameras are worth the investment or if I should wait a bit more...

Comment: Guys! The question is about "Continuous autofocus during recording video"!

Comment: I know you want an interchangeable lens system, but it should be noted that Fujifilm is working on a different solution than Sony- they are putting the phase detection sensor in the imaging sensor. Check out the Fujifilm FinePix HS50EXR. It is not released yet, but available for preorder.

Comment: All Nikon 1 and the Sony NEX-6 also have phase detection sensors buried inside the imaging sensor as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Sony Alpha A55](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/09/23/technology/personaltech/23pogue.html?scp=1&sq=sony%20camera&st=cse) is a new ILC (SLD, actually) camera that can do this.

Comment: Damn that looks like exactly what I wanted, but I hope Canon had a camera that did this, not sure I want to commit to Sony... What do I do now :)

Comment: Technically, the Alpha A55 is an SLT (single lens translucent) not an SLR, as it has a translucent mirror in stead of a reflexive one. This gives it the unique ability to auto-focus during video recording by using its phase-detection AF. As I understand it, that is impossible for any existing SLR on the market, as it is a fundamental shift in camera design. http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sonyslta55/default.asp

Comment: That's true. My question should probably be about "interchangeable lens cameras" rather than "single reflex".

Comment: A 'system camera' is a term too rarely used.

Answer (score 8):

I recently purchased a 7D (with the intent of using its movie capability as well).  I will share my experience.

Like the 5DMkII, the 7D allows you to autofocus during shooting by pressing the shutter button/AF button.  As che suggests in his answer for the 5D, the results are poor if you do this during your live shoot and I would definitely not recommend it.

My focusing workflow: before I start recording, I use autofocus to focus on the target area, and then whilst filming I use manual ring focus.  I found that using the ring focus in this way was much easier than I thought and it also gives far more control over what you can do.

My old video camera was a far cheaper auto focusing one.  Often I wanted to be able to have full control over the focus, either because it would do it wrong or I wanted to do something more creative.  Now I can, and I am not sure I have much desire for full time auto focus for most of the stuff I am shooting...

Comment: Manual focus offers flexibility and I agree that if you shoot anything good you will be using it but still continuous autofocus like the one the Sony A55 seems to offering is a very useful feature that I'd like to have for quick videos in holidays etc.

Answer (score 4):

The new Nikon DSLRs (D3100 and D7000) support that feature.

As for non-DSLRs, the new Sony SLTs (A33 and A55) and the micro-4/3 models (Panasonic GH1 and newly announced GH2).

Comment: I think the new Sony's are a different kind of camera...rather than being a DSLR, they use a translucent mirror.

Comment: Are you sure D7000 supports that? Continuous autofocus during recording video?

Comment: @Ali Yes the D7000 support continuous autofocus on video, but its not what you'd expect. Its quite finicky and there is always the induced noise. I just use manual focus myself.

Comment: For the D3100 it does not do it continuously (even if you select AF-F), but if you half-press the shutter while recording it tries to autofocus using contrast, which more often than not means that the lens goes hunting for focus for 2-3 seconds before it's able to really nail it down (terrible effect). You are often served better using manual focus, even if you slighly miss it.

Comment: You can add the D600 to the list too.  The noise it creates on the recording though is horrendous without an external mic.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out Canon's new [EOS-M](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/about_canon?pageKeyCode=pressreldetail&docId=0901e024805d7bdb). It does continuous autofocus and has the added bonus that you can re-use your canon lenses on it.

Comment: Now that's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Nikon D7000](http://www.dpreview.com/previews/nikond7000/) supports autofocus in movie mode, beyond that most that I'm aware of are manual focus.

Comment: You mean continuous autofocus, or one off when the user wants?

Comment: I believe you can turn it off, it's a focus mode setting on the camera (AF-F) so I would assume switching it to any other would disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Canon EOS 5D Mark II allows you to autofocus when shooting video, but [the results are quite ugly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVg2NaYImOA).

Answer (score 1):

The new Sony a57, a65 and a77 all have super fast autofocus in video. works very well. They also have a very easy manual focus feature that is called peaking mode (I beleive?) that will light up what ever spot is in focus at that time. And you can select a red, white or black color. very cool!

Answer (score 1):

The [Canon T4i](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canon-eos-650d-rebel-t4i) has continuous autofocus during movie record as well.

Actually, for a more comprehensive and up-to-date list, I'd recommend checking out snapsort, which will list all cameras matching a certain feature. In our case: [The best recent DSLRs that can focus continuously while recording movies](http://snapsort.com/explore/best-DSLRs/can-focus-continuously-recording-movies-24-months-recent)

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of old, but it doesn't look like anyone's mentioned the recently released Canon 70D.

The Canon 70D has a new type of AF built into the imaging sensor ("Dual-Pixel CMOS AF"), so can do phase-detect focusing while recording (or in Live View). While many other cameras can do contrast-based focusing (even during recording), this is a big step-up in speed for the DSLR-video market.

Unless using an off-camera microphone, you'll probably also want to combine it with STM (or maybe some USM) lenses, which specifically [reduce the amount of noise generated by the AF mechanism](http://petapixel.com/2013/08/26/video-comparing-canons-usm-and-stm-lenses-using-the-70ds-dual-pixel-af/). They're designed for continual AF adjustments without jolting as they start/stop focusing (which was not important in the design of older single-shot AF motors).

Answer (score 0):

Nikon D3100,3200,5100 and 5200 : these all have the auto focus feature when shooting video...its an awesome feature

Comment: I have a D3100 and the result is quite terrible. Much better going manual focus instead (see my comment above for details).